# A portable, free and simple video editor

Tags: windows, gratis, video-editing, portable, mp4

Is there a free video editor that:

1. do not require to register
2. do not need to install, it is portable
3. do not require to login
4. do not install other unnecessary software
5. have the basic function such as trim, cut, join, split
6. runs on Windows XP and above.
7. takes in at least mp4 file format video (good to have: gif, avi)
8. allows resize of video
9. export to at least mp4. (good to have: avi, gif)
10. Graphical user interface, not web-based.

Answer (score 4):

That software exists, and better yet, it's open source:

### [AviDemux](http://avidemux.sourceforge.net/)

It can cut MP4 files losslessly (hence very fast). It can also apply filters such a resize or rotation and recompress using a variety of codecs, including the award-winning GPL-licensed [x264](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X264).

Comment: *losslessly (hence very fast)* That says: it does it without loss **and therefore** very fast. Are you sure there is a relation between those two properties? Please [edit]

Comment: Yes. Losslessly means without recompression. Recompression is very CPU intensive. Without recompression, the video editor just copies the bytes from one file to another - there's no way to save a clip from a longer movie faster than that.

Answer (score 2):

[VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org) can also open MP4 files with the [FFMpeg Input Plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/virtualdubffmpeginputplugin/). It's small, fast, and open source.

Saving as MP4 is [more complicated](https://encodingtalk.com/threads/virtualdub-save-direct-to-mp4-fraps-to-youtube-with-external-encoders.2446/).